# Php for loop issue

Tags: php

Hi I'm Learning php and trying to do a for loop look like this wtih this code:

```
for($x=1; $x<=20; $x++){
    echo $x;
    $x = $x + 3; //5    
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

It's produce

```
 1
 5
 9
 13
 14
```

But I want it should be...

```
1 
5
10
15
20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are more than one solution.

one is:

```
for($x=1; $x<=20; $x++){
    if(!($x % 5) || $x==1)
        echo $x . "<br />";    
}
```

Explination

`%` is the modulo operator. It returns the devision rest.

lets say `$x` is 3 than `3 % 5` would return 3 because the result 3/5 = 0 rest 3

if its `$x` is 10, it return 0. 10/5 = 2 rest 0

In the if-statement I use `!`-not operator. This turns around the result.

Because `if` takes 1+ (one and more) as `true` and 0- (zero and less) as `false`

So rest of 3 would be positiv (true) but in this case i want it to be false. So I turn arount the true/false with `!`

`%` - Modulo

`R` - Rest

```
1 % 5 = 0 R 1  // would say true to if
2 % 5 = 0 R 2  // would say true to if
3 % 5 = 0 R 3  // would say true to if
4 % 5 = 0 R 4  // would say true to if
5 % 5 = 1 R 0  // would say false to if
6 % 5 = 1 R 1  // would say true to if

and so on...
```

Comment: DanFromGermany has a more efficient answer below. This one loops 20 times when you only need 5 loopings.

Comment: @Shibbir: I don't know how did you accept this answer and you don't understand it

Comment: @LionKing because it works and its tiny. I bet there are many thing in life you do, even if you don't know what really happens. May you drive a care whithout knowing what material the gas made out...

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 20; $x += 5) {
    echo ($x == 0 ? 1 : $x), '<br>';
}
```

Or:

```
foreach (range(0, 20, 5) as $x) {
    echo ($x == 0 ? 1 : $x), '<br>';
}
```

You can't produce the sequence without 1 extra condition because the delta differs in the first step:

```
 1  + 4 ...
 5  + 5
10  + 5
15  + 5
20  + 5
```

Comment: I think the second way is good but it's more slowly than the first way.

Comment: @LionKing It's only a theoretical performance difference, not noticable in such a small use case.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
    $x = 1;

for ($j = 1; $j <= 20; $j++) {

echo $x, "<br/>";
if ($x == 1) {
    $x = $x + 4;
} else {

    $x = $x + 5;
   if($x > 20){break;}
}
}
```

if this answer is work for you please mark the answer.

Comment: I want to stop it to 20.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for($x=1; $x<=20; $x++) {
    if($x%5==0 || $x==1) {
        echo $x;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```